# Magento translation fails

Tags: magento, csv, translation, inline

I have trouble translating the phrase "%s was added to your shopping cart." in magento. This is a message that is called in a php-controller (cartController.php).

I use csv-files for the translation and checked them multiple times for errors (missing quotes, wrong quotes, ...), but the translation still won't work. Translating inline seems also impossible as no option is shown to translate success-messages.

I also checked the store language (which is set to Dutch), locale configuration and via code what language he finds, this all turns out fine, everything is okay.

Does anyone know what next steps I should take to investigate this problem or even better: does anyone know a solution for this problem? I found many threads like this one, but unanswered or without an answer for me.

One more thing: Yes, I cleared my cache and translations ;-).

Tx

Comment: What Magento version are you using?

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that: Magento Enterprise ver. 1.9.1.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to put translate.csv into your theme folder:

```
(root)/app/design/frontend/(theme)/default/locale/nl_NL/translate.csv
```

And put your translation there.

Comment: Funny... I've been searching for this a long time and such a simple thing fixes it. I've tried using f.e (root)/app/design/frontend/(theme)/default/locale/de_DE/Mage_Checkout.csv and that didn't work (used to work...), but this does. Thank you :-)

Comment: Yes. You should put Mage_Checkout.csv to app/locale/de_DE/

Comment: For some reason, those files are not recognized (or at least, they don't work), but the translate.csv file did ;-).

Comment: Uhm, very strange. Perhaps you should check System->Configuration->General->general->Locale settings, might be there is something wrong with your locale. OR Try Design tab under general. THere also might be something with your translations. I don't know if there are some other Locacle related things in Enterprise.

Comment: Yeah, checked those already. It's something to look at when there is time, but for now your solution is okay. Thanks again :-).

Comment: Just a small addition. Dutch would be nl_NL and German(Deutsch) is de_DE.

Answer (score 1):

Check the encoding of your file Mage_Checkout.csv

Probably you have ANSI or UTF-8, but it should be "UTF-8 without BOM", otherwise Magento has troubles in using the translation file.